# Comparison between Modin | Dask | Data.table | Pandas for parallel processing and out of memory csv files

Tags: python, pandas, dask, modin

What are the fundamental difference and primary use-cases for Dask | Modin | Data.table

I checked the documentation of each libraries, all of them seem to offer a 'similar' solution to pandas limitations

Answer (score 13):

I'm trying to decide which tool to learn of the three for parallel / out-of-memory computing: `dask`, `modin` or `datatable` (`pandas` is not a parallel tool, nor is aimed at out-of-memory computing).

Didn't find any out-of-memory tools in `datatable` documentation (discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56572117/does-pythons-datatable-package-support-out-of-memory-datasets)), hence I'm only focusing on `modin` and `dask`.

In short `modin` is trying to be a drop-in replacement for the `pandas` API, while `dask` is lazily evaluated. `modin` is a column store, while `dask` partitions data frames by rows. The distribution engine behind `dask` is centralized, while that of `modin` (called `ray`) is not. **Edit**: Now `modin` supports `dask` as calculation engine too.

`dask` was the first, has large eco-system and looks really well documented, discussed in forums and demonstrated on videos. `modin` (`ray`) has some design choices which allow it to be more flexible in terms of resilience for hardware errors and high-performance serialization. `ray` aims at being most useful in AI research, but `modin` itself is of general use. `ray` also aims at real-time applications to support real-time reinforcement learning better.

More details [here](https://github.com/modin-project/modin/issues/515) and [here](https://github.com/ray-project/ray/issues/642).

Comment: Unless we need to scale to multiple machines, I found Vaex 3-4x faster for simple agg and basic stats. In Dask, each partition should fit into memory i think but i had a combined large file ~50GB

Answer (score 7):

I have a task of dealing with daily stock trading data and came across this post. The length of my rows is about 60 million and length of the columns is below 10. I tested with all 3 libraries in `read_csv` and `groupby mean`. Based upon this little test my choice is `dask`. Below is a comparison of the 3:

```
| library      | `read_csv` time | `groupby` time |
|--------------|-----------------|----------------|
| modin        | 175s            | 150s           |
| dask         | 0s (lazy load)  | 27s            |
| dask persist | 26s             | 1s             |
| datatable    | 8s              | 6s             |
```

It seems that `modin` is not as efficient as `dask` at the moment, at least for my data. `dask persist` tells `dask` that your data could fit into memory so it take some time for dask to put everything in instead of lazy loading. `datatable` originally has all data in memory and is super fast in both read_csv and groupby. However, given its incompatibility with pandas it seems better to use `dask`. Actually I came from R and I was very familiar with R's data.table so I have no problem applying its syntax in python. If `datatable` in python could seamlessly connected to pandas (like it did with data.frame in R) then it would have been my choice.

Comment: How many cores did you distribute to? Could it be that `modin` didn't help due to being a column store, while `dask` partitioning by rows?

Comment: Did  you also save the compute time of pandas itself as the baseline ? Also surprised about modin results

Comment: It has been a while but my memory is that I did not distribute cores, so I should have used the default settings. It was a little test so I think I just record the wall time and did not dig deeper.

Comment: I think finally my choice is to use the default pandas read_csv although the loading is slow. I think I did not choose dask because after many rounds of tweaking my code, getting errors and so on so forth, it was not that fast as I expected for other manipulations of data. So I don't know if these packages are improving or any other suggestions? Is vaex good? I didn't try this but someday I certainly will start another round of searching and testing...

Comment: Cylon provides a DataFrame API with a fully distributed execution. It may be faster for this use case. github.com/cylondata/cylon, Disclaimer, I'm with the Cylon project.