# Does Python's datatable package support out-of-memory datasets?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, hpc

`datatable` is a relatively fresh high performance DataFrame/data.table alternative for Python. The `datatable` [documentation](https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) states:

`It focuses on: big data support, high performance, both in-memory 
and out-of-memory datasets, and multi-threaded algorithms.`

Still, haven't found operations related to caching or keeping a part of the data out-of-memory. In what sense does it support out-of-memory datasets?

Comment: If you have big data , I recommend dask

Comment: @WeNYoBen, my data first the memory of our servers for now, just curious what different frameworks can offer... I'm looking at dask and modin as well, thanks!